# Install Facebook APK in Microsoft Android Emulator

Tags: facebook, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

I am using the Microsoft Android emulator that comes with Visual Studio 2015.  It works great overall but I cannot find a Facebook APK that works on it.  Has anyone solved this problem?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Facebook currently only offers an ARMv7 build of their APK on the [SDK downloads page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads). Your virtual android device must run in an ARMv7 emulator as well for that APK to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to get the Google Play Store on the emulator then download the Facebook APK from Google Play. To do that, you might try this: http://codesmells.net/2015/07/27/installing-the-google-play-store-in-the-microsoft-visual-studio-android-emulator/